# Upload video with large size using Alamofire

Tags: swift, xcode, video, upload, alamofire

Trying to be able to upload large video files using Alamofire where video size can be in GB. I just need to figure out how I can upload the videos of such size to server.

```
func uploadVideo(videoUrl: URL) { // local video file path..
    let timestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 // just for some random name.

    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        multipartFormData.append(videoUrl, withName: "image", fileName: "\(timestamp).mp4", mimeType: "\(timestamp)/mp4")
    }, to: endPoint!  ).responseJSON { (response) in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: I want to resume downloading when in background or when user enter in application after app terminated etc and resume download from last progress.

Comment: @DeshRajThakur find any solution so far ??